# Problem with installing a Symfony project

Tags: symfony, composer-php

When I make this command line : `composer create-project symfony/skeleton my_project_directory`, I get this error:

```
[RuntimeException]
 require.beberlei/DoctrineExtensions is invalid, it should not contain uppercase characters. Please use beberlei/doc
 trineextensions instead.
```

I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Is this a docker thing or some sort of custom project creation script?  Because the skeleton does not install doctrine at all let alone any custom extensions.

Comment: As pointed out @[Nico Haase](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1116230/nico-haase), `beberlei/doctrineextensions` isn't part of core packages installed by `composer create-project` command. Which version of composer / symfony are you using ? Have you run other command such as `composer require beberlei/doctrineextensions` ? Are you following this documentation ? -> [Installing & Setting up the Symfony Framework](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html#creating-symfony-applications)

Answer (score 2):

Just read the error message, it explain how to fix it:

> require.beberlei/DoctrineExtensions is invalid, it should not contain uppercase characters. Please use beberlei/doc trineextensions instead.

In your composer.json file, you have to lowercase `beberlei/DoctrineExtensions` to `beberlei/doctrineextensions`.

If you're not familiar whith Symfony, composer.json file is the file where you populate packages that your project require using composer (similar to package.json used by npm). More info at: [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md)

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. A `composer.json` generated through the given line shouldn't even contain that dependency

Answer (score 0):

in composer.json file of your project just change **"beberlei/DoctrineExtensions"** by **"beberlei/doctrineextensions"** and you relaunch composer install

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. A composer.json generated through the given line shouldn't even contain that dependency

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).